# Confused about the form of a functor between sets viewed as categories

Tags: category-theory, functors

For completeness, this is the definition of a functor I am working with:

[image]

My textbook says that

> A functor between sets $S$ and $T$ is a function from $S$ to $T$.

I tried proving this fact. To keep it short, I deduced that all other properties of these kinds of functors (i.e., functors being functions between sets $S$ and $T$) follow from $F_1(\mathsf{1}_A) = \mathsf{1}_{F_0A}$. Because all arrows in $T$ are identities, it surely follows that $F_1(\mathsf{1}_A) = \mathsf{1}_{B}$, but here I get stuck. Without additional information, it seems that the condition $F_1(\mathsf{1}_A) = \mathsf{1}_{F_0A}$ could fail, because $F_1$ could map some $f$ to $Ff : B \to B$, but because there are no constraints on $F_0$, it could be the case that $F_0A \neq B$.

I've gone through the definition carefully and I failed to find an additional premise which would constrain $F_0$ as needed. It seems that the crucial question here is *what exactly does it mean for a functor to be a function between sets $S$ and $T$, viewed as categories.* After all, a functor has a richer structure than a simple function between sets, being a *pair of functions* $(F_0, F_1)$.

Thank you for your help. This question is especially important, as I cannot proceed in studying category theory without a clear understanding of the structure of functors.

*Addendum.* $\mathcal{C}_0$ denotes the class of the objects of a category $\mathcal{C}$, and $\mathcal{C}_1$ the class of its morphisms/arrows.

Comment: I assume the subscript 0 on a category denotes its objects and 1 its morphisms? If this is the case, you might consider putting that in your question; this isn't standard notation for category theory.

Comment: @kamills Yep, $\mathcal{C}_0$ denotes the class of the objects of a category $\mathcal{C}$, and $\mathcal{C}_1$ the class of its morphisms/arrows. Will add to the post, thanks!

Comment: Anyway, the point is that a functor must specify where it sends objects and where it sends morphisms. If you view a set as a category whose objects are the set-elements and whose morphisms are just the identity arrows for each set-element, then the data of a functor from one set to another is precisely specifying where the objects (in this case, set-elements) of your domain category go. Since all arrows in $S$ and $T$ are already identity mappings, you're done.

Comment: But I showed this is not enough. I can choose such $F_0$ and $F_1$ that $F_1(\mathsf{1}_A) \neq \mathsf{1}_{F_0A}$.

Comment: I don't think you can: if you have an arrow $A \to A$ in $S$, it must be the identity map. Then $F_0 A$ is some element of (the set) $T$, and there is only one arrow $F_0 A \to F_0 A$, namely the identity map. So if you want to specify $F_1$ you're forced to choose $F_1 (1_A) = 1_{F_0 A}$. The full details of this sort of argument are in FShrike's answer below, though.

Comment: The misunderstanding here was that I thought that for *any* $F_1$ and $F_0$ you choose, $F$ must be a functor. @FShriek pointed out to me that I must choose $F_1$ in a specific way for $F$ to be a functor. In other words, it was unclear to me *how* the functor $F$ was generated from the function $f$. It turns out that $F_0 = f$, which determines $F_1$ uniquely.

Answer (score 3):

All other properties of functors do not follow from $F_1(1_A)=1_{F_0A}$, at least not in general. However, if you are viewing sets as so-called "discrete" categories, then what you have said is true, because the only arrow $A\to A'$ in $S$ will just be an identity arrow $A\to A$.

So long as $F_1(1_A)$ is an arrow $F_0A\to F_0A$ (i.e. has correct domain and codomain) then it equals $1_{F_0A}$ by uniqueness, as you say. But this is always true by definition of a functor - you are worrying in the wrong direction, I think? If you are *given* a functor $F$, then you already know $F_1(1_A)=1_{F_0A}$, you don't need to prove that. If you are *constructing* a functor $F$, then you are in control of $F_0$ and $F_1$, and $F_1f$ is always forced (for any arrow $f$) to have domain $F_0A$ and codomain $F_0A'$ if $f$'s domain and codomain are $A,A'$ respectively. So there *is* a constraint, you are forced by law to make that choice. Again, it is up to you to construct $F_1$, but there is actually only one thing you can do.

The thing about discrete categories is that if $S$ is a discrete category and $C$ is any other category, and if you are given $F_0:S_0\to C_0$, there is one and only one way to extend $F_0$ to a functor. This is for exactly the reasons mentioned: $F_1$ must have the right domains and codomains and the only arrows you need to define $F_1$ for are identity arrows, which are obliged to be sent to identity arrows by law. Hence, one and only one way to do it.

This realisation is really the point of the exercise, so think on it.

If you have $F_0,F_1$ given and want some $f:S\to T$, then all you need to do is find, for every point $s\in S$, a point $t\in T$ which you can call $f(s)$. If you want to do this in a way related to $F_0,F_1$, consider that $s$ is an object of the category $S$, so $F_0(s)$ is an object of the category $T$ and can be understood as an element of $t$. So "what it means for a functor to be a function..." is that any functor "descends" to a function $S_0\to T_0$, in this case $S=S_0,T=T_0$, so your desired $f:S\to T$ is just simply $F_0$. You can ignore the data of $F_1$ because, as said, $F_1$ is uniquely determined by $F_0$ (it adds no new information).

Going the other way, any $f:S\to T$ creates an $F_0:S_0\to T_0$, which creates an $F_1:S_1\to T_1$ in a unique way, which creates your functor $F$.

Comment: Thanks, this clarifies some things. Yes, I am interested in the direction $\text{function} \Rightarrow \text{functor}$, as the textbook claims. I guess what you are saying is that any function $f : S \to T$ is $F_0$ which uniquely generates $F_1$. That's what I was looking for. The functor $F$ is "the function $f$" in this specific sense. It cannot be literally identical to it, since it is a pair of functions. Though I am a little disappointed that the textbook didn't mention this important fact.

Comment: @Godbless It is not literally identical to it, no. I'm afraid that in category theory and in pretty much all higher mathematics, authors make extensive use of "identifications" and "obvious *this* is identifiable with *that*" etc. This - to the person who knows what's going on - makes things simpler, but is really confusing for a student who's new to the topic. It's important to (a) grow comfortable with "identifying" whilst simultaneously (b) always being aware that things are technically not the same. This is, I suppose, related to (cont.)

Comment: @Godbless (cont.) [Tao's "post-rigorous" philosophy](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/)